# multiple hyperlinks calling one servlet which decides the page to be displayed

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, hyperlink

you see i'm trying to make a simple navigation menu in trying to make just a simple web app.
i wanted to try atleast 2 menu that uses only one form.
when any of the menu is clicked, it will call the servlet MainServlet which will be the one that will decide which JSP page to be displayed.

In JSP:

```
<form action="menu" method="POST">
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MainServlet" name="about">About</a>
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MainServlet" name="contact">Contact Us</a>
</form>
```

In web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.javashuffle.servlets.MainServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/MainServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In MainServlet:

```
doGet() {
   if (request.getParameter("about") != null) {
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("about.jsp");
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
   } else if (request.getParameter("contact") != null) {
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp");
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
   }
}
```

i cant seem to go to the desired JSP page using my codes in the servlet.
what do you think is the problem with my codes?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The URL of each of the links is exactly the same, and doesn't include any parameter. For your code to work the URLs should be

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MainServlet?about=
```

and

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MainServlet?contact=
```

I would use two different servlets instead: one which has the responsibility of dealing with the about page, and the other one that has the responsibility to deal with the contact page. It doesn't change much if all they do is dispatch to a JSP, but if some data is needed to display in the pages, having a dedicated servlet for each page makes more sense.

It would also help having cleaner URLs, like `/contact` and `/about`.

Comment: if different servlets for each link is the recommended idea,
may i ask if this kind of programming technique also applied in making 'bigtime' applications? thanks

Comment: I don't know what a "bigtime" application is. Please clarify.

Comment: bigtime application like any other outstanding websites in the internet today like company websites, business websites and any other websites made by professional developers.

Comment: Each application has its best practices. Many of them are written in Java, and many of them are not. Most of the Java apps I have been involved in don't use servlets directly, but use an MVC framework (Stripes, Spring MVC, etc.). But whatever the technology is, the single responsibility principle is a good and well-known principle. A servlet that has the responsibility of getting the data necessary for all the pages accessible from a menu has way too many responsibilities.